# Displaying in QGIS a TIFF product exported from GEE

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, watershed

I am new in GEE and am attempting to export and use a tiff product (WWF HydroSHEDS Basins Level 9) from GEE (output image, details, and code are shown below). The problem comes when importing and displaying such ouput in QGIS, as it doesn't show anything (the whole raster appears in white). I am not sure whether the problem is in the code or it's simply a matter of band rendering in QGIS layer properties when visualising the raster.

```
var AOI = ee.FeatureCollection
("projects/ee-marsuarezmoreno/assets/56_P_NE_Watersheds");

var watersheds = ee.FeatureCollection
("WWF/HydroSHEDS/v1/Basins/hybas_9");

watersheds = watersheds.style({
  color: "white",
  width: 3.0,
});

var clipped = watersheds.clip(AOI);

Map.addLayer(clipped, {color: 'blue'}, 'AOI_watershed');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clipped,
  description: 'clipped_watershed',
  scale: 30,
  region: AOI
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since the watershed data is actually a set of polygons, I suggest trying to use Export.table.toDrive instead, that way you get a shapefile or kml instead of a raster. Also as a side note rather than using clip I would use filterBounds and that way you obtain the full watersheds that intersect your AOI instead of a clipped section.

Comment: Thank you @MadeleineNicolas for your answer. You were right, I changed it to "Export.table.toDrive" especifically to 'SHP' and this time I was able to display it in QGIS.